# Setting CheckBoxes from another userform in VBA

Tags: vba, checkbox, userform

I have a userform which contains a number of checkboxes from 1 to 100. I have written some very simple code so that when you submit the form it creates a binary string that represents the state of those 100 checkboxes, where 0 is false and 1 is true. The code to do this is here:

```
Private Sub BusRulesSubmit_Click()
 Dim myBinaryString As String
 Dim nm As String
 Dim c As Control

 For busRuleIdx = 1 To 100
  nm = "CheckBox" & busRuleIdx
  Set c = Controls(nm)
  If c.Value = True Then
   myBinaryString = myBinaryString & "1"
  Else
   myBinaryString = myBinaryString & "0"
  End If
 Next

 msgBox myBinaryString
End Sub
```

I now want to open this Userform from another form, where I have a similar binary string, and use this string to set the values of the checkboxes to true or false as appropariate. However I am having issues when setting my control. The code is here:

```
Private Sub populateBusRules()
 Dim c As Control
 Dim myBRBinary As String
 myBRBinary =    "000000000011100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000"

 For busRuleIdx = 1 To 100
  nm = "BusinessRules.CheckBox" & busRuleIdx
  Set c = Controls(nm)
  If Mid(myBRBinary, buRuleIdx - 1, 1) = 1 Then
   c.Value = True
  Else
   c.Value = False
  End If
 Next
End Sub
```

When I run the above, I get a runtime error "Could not find the specified object" and when going to debug it highlights this problem where the code states "Set c = Controls(nm)" - and I can see that it is failing in the first round of the loop i.e. where nm = "BusinessRules.CheckBox1"

Interestingly if I run the code "Set c = Controls(BusinessRules.CheckBox1)" I get no such issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Paul.

Comment: Hi, how proficient are you in VBA?  Does the original form stay open?

Comment: You will need global variables if the forms are not opened at the same time.

Comment: Yes The forms are open at the same time - though I use hide commands

Comment: Can you reference form to form frm2.control.value=frm1.control.value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `BusinessRules` is giving you the issue.  In the Controls collection, there is no Control named `"BusinessRules.CheckBox1"`, only one named `"CheckBox1"` within the `BusinessRules.Controls` collection.  Assuming there aren't other issues mentioned in the comments above (like the form being closed before this is called), then this should fix your issue

Comment: Great that makes perfect sense. So this gets resolved by using "Set c = BusinessRules.Controls(nm)"